# occupation measure

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, characteristic-functions

Let $H$ be the Heaviside step function $H:t\in \mathbb{R}\mapsto \mathbb{R}\ni H(t)$.

The measure 
$$
\nu(dt,dx) = \delta_0(dx) I_{]-\infty,0]}(dt) +
\delta_1(dx)I_{[0,+\infty[}(dt),
$$
where $I$ is the characteristic function and $\delta$ is the Dirac generalized function, is supported on the graph of $H$ and is called an occupation measure for $H$.
*The notation $\nu(dt,dx)$ stands for the measure $d\nu(t,x)$
so that $\delta_0(dx)$ is in fact the measure (and not the generalized function) $\delta_0(x)dx$.*
Then, for two Borel sets $A,B$,
$$
\nu(A\times B) = \int_{A\times B} d\nu= \int_{A\times B} \delta_0(x)I_{]-\infty,0]}(t)\;dtdx
$$

---

Now, consider the function
$$
f(t) = t, \qquad t\in [0,1].
$$

1. Can we write an occupation measure for $f$ as a product between a measure depending on $t$ only and a measure depending on $x$ only ?

---

### From the general viewpoint

Consider the measure $\nu$ supported on a trajectory : $[0,T] \ni t\mapsto x(t) \in X\subset \mathbb{R}$.

Given tow Borel sets $A\subset [0,T],B\subset X$, we can measure the time spent by the trajectory in $B$ during a duration $A$ by computing
$$
\nu(A\times B) = \int_A I_{B}(x(t))\; dt \qquad (\dagger).
$$

Applying the disintegration theorem to $\nu$ between the sets $[0,T]\times X$ and $T$ ([wiki source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem))
, we have
$$
\nu(A\times B) = \int_A \nu(B\mid t)\, \nu(\pi^{-1}(dt)) 
$$
where

- $\pi$ is the canonical projection on $[0,T]$,
- $\nu(B\mid t)$ is the condition expectation : for each $t$, this is a measure on the fiber $\pi^{-1}(\{t\})$, so that $\nu(B\mid t) = \nu(([0,T]\times B)\cap \pi^{-1}(\{t\})$,
- $\nu(\pi^{-1}(dt))$ should be equal to $dt$ since $\pi^{-1}(dt)$ is
  an infinitesimal area w.r.t to $t$ and we measure the time with the Lebesgue measure?

---

The theorem says that such decomposition is unique and that $\nu(.\mid t)$ is a probability measure on $X$.
Regarding $(\dagger)$, $\nu(B\mid t)=I_{B}(x(t))$ and $I_{.}(x(t))$ is  a probability measure on $X$.

Comment: In this context you should think of $\delta_a$ is a measure, not a generalized function. It is defined by $\delta_a(A)=I_A(a)$, i.e. $\delta_a(A)=1$ if $a\in A$ and $0$ otherwise. So I agree that $\delta_0(dx)$ makes sense, for instance. But $I_{(0,\infty)}(dt)$ does not. What does $f(dt)$ mean if $f$ is a real-valued function? Do you perhaps mean $f(t)dt$? That would make the most sense, as then for instance the subset $(-3,-1)\times\{0\}$ would have $\nu$-measure $2$, as one would hope for something called an "occupation measure".

Comment: Ah, I see you edited your post before my comment. Sorry about that!

Comment: $\ni(A\times B) = \int_{A\times B} \delta_0(x) I_{]-\infty,0]}(t) dtdx$ can be integrated iteratively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then to answer the first question, we write
$$
\nu(A\times B) = \int_A I_B(t) \; dt 
$$
and we would like to find $d\nu(t,x)$ such that 
$$
\int_A I_B(t) \; dt  = \int_{A\times B}d\nu(t,x). 
$$
We have
$$
\int_A I_B(t) \; dt = \int_A \delta_t(B)\, dt = \int_A \left(\int_B d\delta_t(x)\right) dt
$$
so 
$$
d\nu(t,x) = d\delta_t(x)\, dt.
$$